# make a div that flow with scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to make div that flow when i scroll the page.
and that div has to stop in b point, it don't need to flow to entire page

i make a div with position fixed but it flow to entire page.
I want it to stop flow on point b

```css
#sumario {
  position: fixed;
  right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sumario" class="col-md-3">
  <div id="status" class="card mt-5">
    <div class="card-body">
      <table class="able">
        <thead class="thead-deault">
          <tr>
            <th>
              <h1 class="font-weight-bold">{{translation.SUMARY}}</h1>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{translation.WP}}</th>
            <td>Nina</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{translation.PICKUP_DATE}}</th>
            <td>dd-mm-yyy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{translation.TOTAL}}</th>
            <td>0000$</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i have to point A(init) and B(end), i want the div to flow on point A to point B and then stop there

Comment: You'll need to use scripting to calculate the stopping point. Have you tried?

Comment: You can use css position:sticky property
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_sticky_element

Answer (score 0):

What about using position: absolute and define top value as *elem*.style.top = window.scrollY + "px", then use a condition to stop scrolling when the condition is met

Answer (score 0):

this is a way that i found

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var $height = $(window).scrollTop();
    this.console.log($height)
  if($height > 950) {
        $('#sumario').removeClass('sumario');
        $('#sumario').addClass('sumario2');
        this.console.log($height)
    } else {
        $('#sumario').removeClass('sumario2');
        $('#sumario').addClass('sumario');
    }
});
```